# Java TCP Server is not reading the file content

Tags: java, serversocket

The Java program for TCP Server and TCP Client are below. I have placed the file that has to be read in the same folder where my Java programs exist. Now, when I enter the file name from TCP Client, the TCP Server throws the output as **File not found**. Where am I wrong? Your help is really appreciated.

#### TCP SERVER

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class TcpServer{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
        ServerSocket ss = null;
        Socket s = null;
        try{
            ss = new ServerSocket(3000);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while(true){
            try{
                System.out.println("Server Ready....");
                s = ss.accept();
                System.out.println("Client Connected...");
                InputStream istream = s.getInputStream();
                Scanner fread = new Scanner(new 
                        InputStreamReader(istream));
                String fileName = fread.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Reading contents of " + fileName);
                Scanner contentRead = new Scanner(new 
                        FileReader(fileName));
                OutputStream ostream = s.getOutputStream();
                PrintWriter pwrite = new PrintWriter(ostream , true);
                while(contentRead.hasNext())
                    pwrite.println(contentRead.nextLine());
                pwrite.close();
                s.close();
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                OutputStream ostream = s.getOutputStream();
                PrintWriter pwrite = new PrintWriter(ostream , true);
                System.out.println("File Not Found");
                pwrite.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### TCP CLIENT

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TcpClient{
    public static void main( String[] args ){
        Socket s;
        while(true){
            try{
                s = new Socket("127.0.0.1",3000);
                OutputStream ostream = s.getOutputStream();
                System.out.println("Enter filename");
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                String fname = input.nextLine();
                PrintWriter pwrite = new PrintWriter(ostream, true);
                pwrite.println(fname);
                InputStream istream = s.getInputStream();
                Scanner cRead = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(istream));
                while(cRead.hasNext())
                    System.out.println(cRead.nextLine());
                pwrite.close();
                s.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you run the server/client application on a windows system. I think this is a path-name related issue. Therefore you might pass the filename with double backslash as following example shows:

```
C:\\Documents and Settings\\user\\test.txt
```